# Change Angular Material component colors in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular webpage which has a login page and I use angular material in the entire page. 
I want to modify the input color to white instead the color defined by indigo theme.

This is de input to modify in the component 'login.component.html':

```
      <mat-card-content>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="{{ 'forms.username' | translate }}"
        type="text"
        formControlName="username"
        class="form-control"
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }"
      />
      <mat-error
        *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors"
        class="invalid-feedback"
      >
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">
          {{ "error.userRequired" | translate }}
        </mat-error>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This component has its own 'login.component.scss' and I use this to modify the input color:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
  .mat-form-field-label {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;

  }
  .mat-form-field-underline {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

I know 'ng-deep' is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) but I don't find any solutions that works with ':host'.

**The problem is that** when I use 'ng-deep' in 'login.component.scss'the input color changes in the entire page, I mean, it changes in another components and not only in the login component.
Could someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The topic is all about style encapsulation. Angular does this on a component basis, that's why it's so difficult to overwrite the style of existing components.

What you want to achieve is to be able to overwrite styles simply as it works in pure html and css.

In order, to do that, you can create a component, where you set the `encapsulation` property (https://angular.io/api/core/Component) to `ViewEncapsulation.None`. From that point, whatever you write into your scss applies globally, so it's your responsibility to 'protect' your other components.

You can achieve this by applying a proper class on the container element and using the same selector for the changes you make.

html:
`<div class="login-page">...</div>`

scss:
`.login-page { // Add your overwrite rules, it will apply just for the login page ... }`

Notes:

- When you use the ViewEncapsulation.None mode, the :host selector can't be used anymore
- You don't need ng-deep in this case